# How to Implementing Long-Running Tasks like android in ios

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, ftp, image-uploading

I want implementing my ios with uploading large number of image to ftp server for a long-running task in *background*. Because situation may be rise data connection may loose or large number of image may take large time or application is not running in foreground or if is in forground user would be involve in other 
activity.

Please reply me its perfect solution, that i can implement according to apple guide line.

Comment: You post is looking a lot like a code request, this might get you downvoted of your question could be closed a to broad.  Please post any attempts that you tried yourself.

Answer (score 1):

create one back ground queue then upload your data in that queue , it will not effect main queue.

```
dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0);



    // Run request on background queue (thread).
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
//upload image in web service here
});
```

Comment: This will still be canceled if the app goes in to the background. Since you have not setup the Long-Running task.

Comment: thanks  rckoenes and Tejas Ardeshna.but my main concern is the Long-Running task like android how could it be possible I have already apple read document about Long-Running task its work with in build functional app like newsstand or music app.

Comment: it has limitation you cant create same task like build in apps.

Comment: for a image upload you can upload it with using queue.but it won't work while app is in background.